# How to modify consumed webservice and produce another webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I am consuming a web service(REST) in spring boot and the data is json and the format is as shown below:

```
  {
    "id": 679,
    "score": 3
    },
      {
    "id": 682,
    "score": 3
    },
      {
    "id": 692,
    "score": 3
    }
```

After consuming the data I have to produce a web service which delivers the data in JSON as shown below

```
{
   status:{
            "code":"OK",
            "message":"success"
           }

  data:[
        {
        "id": 679,
        "score": 3
        },
          {
        "id": 682,
        "score": 3
        },
          {
        "id": 692,
        "score": 3
        }
       ]
}
```

So currently what I do is in the controller part is

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/data",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<List<Model>> getBooking(@RequestParam("lat")double latitude,@RequestParam("lon") double longitude,@RequestParam("id") int id){



            list=getapi(latitude,longitude,id);
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Model>>(list,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        @ResponseBody   
        public List<Model>  getapi(double latitude,double longitude,int id){
            List<Model> list = Arrays.asList(restTemplatestreetapi.getForObject("http://dataurl, Model[].class));

            return list;

}
```

My current Model class is like

```
public class Model {

    int id;
    int score;

    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }




}
```

I consume the service and produce it directly.But instead of this I want to produce the result as above.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the response entity type in your code e.g

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseClass> getBooking(@RequestParam("lat")double latitude,@RequestParam("lon") double longitude,@RequestParam("id") int id){
```

Define your response class as per your requirement like

```
public class ResponseClass {

private Status status;

/**
 * If no error found use this method for response
 * 
 * @param message
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public static ResponseEntity<ResponseClass> ok(Object data) {
    ResponseClass response = new ResponseClass();
    response.getStatus.setMessage.setCode("ok");
    response.getStatus.setMessage("success")

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
} }

public class Status {
private String message;
private String code;
//Getter Setter
}
```

Return ResponseClass with list as data

```
return ResponseClass.ok(list);
```

You can also add error status in ResponseClass

Comment: I updated the question and you can see my Model.java which is the Model class(Response class) which has the id and the score as a attributes of the Model object.Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @RKR your model class must remain unchanged as per your requirement. You just need to create one more class, to reformat your response. Change return type of _getBooking_ class to _ResponseEntity<your class>_. You can refer to my code snippet above to create your response class. Hope this explanation helps you